# Usage of Application Info , Package Info and Resolve Info

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-fragments

What is the use of Application info and how to use it.
I'm confused how to retrieve the installed apps from the device and to display it with logo
Can anyone please help me to sort it out.
Differentiate the terms applicaiton info, package info and resolve info.

Answer (score 5):

to display a list of installed apps, you can try this

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

You will get all the necessary data in the ResolveInfo to start a application. You can check [ResolveInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html)

or try this code

```
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    ArrayList<ResolveInfo> list = (ArrayList<ResolveInfo>) 
        pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {
        System.out.println("Installed Applications " + rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
        }
```